# Transforming some codes on weighted chi-square tests into functions of variables

Tags: r, function, chi-squared

I have a code that does weighted chi-square tests. It also takes the p-value and add it into a dataset. I would like to transform the code into a function where the arguments is the variable names. The data (called) looks something like that:

```
Gender  UserStatus  Weight
Female  HC          1.3
Male    IDP         0.8
Male    HC          1.3
Male    V           1.1
Female  IDP         0.8
Female  HC          1.3
Female  IDP         0.8
Male    HC          1.3
Female  IDP         0.8
Male    IDP         0.8
Male    IDP         0.8
Female  IDP         0.8
Female  V           1.1
Male    IDP         0.8
Male    V           1.1
Female  HC          1.3
Male    IDP         0.8
Male    V           1.1
  ....
```

The code without the function looks like this:

```
#Create the empty database
dTests <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
colnames(dTests) <- c('var1', 'var2', 'pvalue')

#Affiliate the weight to the data
dGenderUserStatus <- data %>%
  filter(!is.na(Gender) & !is.na(UserStatus)) %>%
  as_survey_design(weights = Weight)

#Calculate the Chi square p-value
pvalue <- svychisq( ~ Gender + UserStatus, dGenderUserStatus) %>% 
.$p.value

#add row
dTests[nrow(dTests) + 1,] <- c("Gender","UserStatus", pvalue)
```

The function - that I attempted to write and for which it does not work - looks something like that:

```
   #Create the empty database
    dTests <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
    colnames(dTests) <- c('var1', 'var2', 'pvalue')
    
FctChiSquareTestGender <- function(data,Var,weight){
  dGenderVar <- data %>%
    filter(!is.na(Gender) & !is.na(get(Var))) %>%
    as_survey_design(weights = {{weight}})

  pvalue <- svychisq( ~ Gender + get(Var), dGenderVar) %>% 
    .$p.value

  #add row
  dTests[nrow(dTests) + 1,] <- c("Gender",Var, pvalue)

    }
FctChiSquareTestGender(data,"UserStatus",Weight)
```

Unfortunately, the code does not work from the pvalue creation with the function "svychisq" when I call "get(Var)". I get this error message:
[image]

Do you have any idea on what I should do about get(Var) so that this code works?

Thanks in advance,

Stephanie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you don't need to use `get(Var)` in the formula, you can just use the string `Var`:

```r
Gender <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
statuses <- c("HC", "IDP", "V")
Userstatus <- replicate(sample(statuses, 1), n = 100)

myfunction <- function(Var){
  form <- as.formula(paste("~ Gender", Var, sep = "+"))
  form
}
myfunction("Userstatus")
#> ~Gender + Userstatus
#> <environment: 0x55ba8badbbf0>
```

And you put `form` in place of the formula input to `svychisq()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried your technique and it gives me an error related to one of the argument called "design". It might be that the fact of putting "paste" does not enter a recognnizable format of variable. I tried: _pvalue <- svychisq(paste0("~ Gender", Var, sep= "+"),dGenderYearVar).$p.value_. I also tried other ways and still does not work. What do you think? Thanks a lot

Comment: `paste0()` does not have a `sep` argument, use `paste()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @philiptomk! It gives me the same error with `paste()`.  `pvalue <- svychisq(paste("~ Gender", Var, sep= "+"),dGenderYearVar) %>%      .$p.value`  The error is: `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Try this instead: `pvalue <- svychisq(as.formula(paste("~ Gender", Var, sep= "+")),dGenderYearVar)$p.value`

Comment: Thank you so so so much!! The test is working but the putting the value of the p-value is not working on the next line: `dTests[nrow(dTests) + 1,] <- c("Gender",Var, pvalue)`. Any clue why? Again thank you for making the test work!

Comment: Try `<<-` instead of `<-`. It has to do with the fact that `<-` assigns to variables in the current environment.